# xdg-open tries to open URLs as files on LXDE

Tags: lxde, browser, url, xdg-open

I run

```
$ xdg-open 'http://google.com'
```

in `/home/rominf/` and expect Firefox to open Google, but instead got GUI message with error:

```
/home/rominf/http:/google.com: No such file or directory
```

Firefox is set as a default browser in LXDE settings. What's wrong with `xdg-open`?

**UPD0:** In the comments, `xdg-mime` was suggested. I set firefox to be the default browser with no success:

```
$ xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
$ xdg-open 'http://google.com' # Produces same error                                     
$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
firefox.desktop
```

**UPD1:**

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype 'http://google.com'
xdg-mime: file 'http://google.com' does not exist
```

The question is: "Why xdg utils think that this link is a filename?".

**UPD2:**

```
$ xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler http                               
firefox.desktop
```

Comment: What is the output of `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
`

Comment: `$ xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http`

`google-chrome.desktop`

Comment: May be `xdg-open` is considering this link as file, so what is the output of `xdg-mime query filetype 'http://google.com'`

Comment: I don't know if "`default-url-scheme-handler http`" and "`x-scheme-handler/http`" could diverge, but what is the output of  `xdg-settings get default-url-scheme-handler http`